# Lightning Flows Multiselect Picklist replicate in Lignting

Tags: lightning, component

Is there a way I can replicate lightning flow's multi select picklist into a lightning component ?(Lightning select usually has drop downs) Below is the image of flows multi select picklist
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the [lightning:dualListbox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:dualListbox) component.